# How to created this type of layout correctly (containing PHP)

Tags: php, html, css

Right what I am trying to do is create a layout like the image below :-
[image: Layout]
This layout will be used for over 50+ pages, so I would like to know the best way to go about creating this. I have given it ago but I can't seem to get my head around how this should work.

I have been trying to get it to work like so:

**header.php** - Holds the side bars. Sidebar 1 `float: left;` and sidebar 2 `float: right` and these are in a container to hold them in place.

**index.php** - Hold content such as a table with stats about the user (in a HTML table). This is wrapped in a div (main content). At the top of the page I `include("header.php");`. This does work but when the PHP at the top of the page uses `echo` the value will not be within the div.

Basically the layout I created is here:- [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/MgjqK/7/)

This is how I want the layout to look but now here is the problem. I am using PHP to calculate stuff e.g:

```
if($userhp <= 0) {
  echo "You are dead";
}
```

Now this code is located at the top of the page, this means it would echo out before the div (for the main content) was opened. Should this code be within the div?

The thing is this example is within a larger `if` statement so I would have to bring that down with it, some of these blocks can be 100+ lines of code.

So I'm not sure how to go about this, a nudge in the right direction would be great.

If you need anymore information or I didn't make something clear enough please leave a comment and I will get back to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php). You can store your output in a variable and print it later in your div:

```
<?
ob_start(); // Turn on output buffering
if ($userhp <= 0) {
    echo "You're dead";
}
...
$contents = ob_get_clean(); // Store output in $contents
...
?>

<div id="content"><?php echo $contents ?></div>
```

Comment: Had a little look into this, is this safe to use? Will it cause me any problems (common problems that you know of)

Comment: Yes it is safe to use, for example the Zend Framework (http://framework.zend.com/) also uses this technique to place page content into the layout. There are no common problems I can think of. If you forget to close the output buffering (ob_get_clean or on_end_flush and others) the output will be automatically send to the browser at the end of your script, so you can't lose data (in case your script terminates early due to an error).

Comment: Only problem maybe is that all output is stored in memory, but that only becomes an issue when you are showing a really really large page (for example displaying a 10MB-large image using PHP). With a normal HTML-page you're only speaking of a few kb max.

Comment: I'm going to use this, thanks for the help!